# Fargate calls to AWS Secrets Manager timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to get my VPC-connected Fargate instances to call the AWS Secrets Manager API, but in doing so the call is timing out:

> Connect to secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443
>   [secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/172.31.65.102,
>   secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/172.31.66.72,
>   secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/172.31.64.251] failed: connect
>   timed out

I am aware that as of earlier this year in Fargate 1.3.0 you can get the secrets injected in as environment variables as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html). In fact, I have that type of integration working great!

My issue is that I am unable to fetch the exact same secret programmatically using the Secret Manager SDK. When I do, I get the above timeout. In addition to the appropriate policy on the IAM `ecsTaskExecutionRole` role (which is what enabled me to get the secret via env variable), I also added a VPC Endpoint (because my Fargate instances are on VPC) as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html). My Fargate instances are regularly talking to the outside internet as well.

Any ideas on what else could cause the timeout?

Comment: timeout mean the fargate service is not able to talk, can do with in code something like `ping google.com`

Comment: To use VPC endpoints transparently, you must enable the checkbox that says enable local DNS. This makes DNS in your VPC substitute the new Secrets Manager endpoint when the application looks up the Secrets Manager endpoint address.

Also, make sure you the security group on the VPC endpoint opens up the endpoint to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the problem was ultimately some unwise route entries. Thanks to the comments for reminding me that the error was a timeout and thus upstream from any IAM configuration issues. That helped me focus exclusively on network-related solutions.

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem. Can you explain what type of route entries might cause this?